# The event of notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview

I have class  Myadapter extends BaseAdapter.in Myadapter  i changed the MyListView data then call notifyDataSetChanged() method,like remove an item(click  button on a listview item),it works perfect.but how can we refresh the view that except listview in Activity. especially can i get some event when notifyDataSetChanged() is called?then we can notify ui thread to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this manually:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
callCustomMethod(); // Updates custom view
```

Comment: no,I call notifyDataSetChanged() in MyAdapter,but how can i get this event in an Activity;thanks all the same

Comment: thanks,although it's not answer that i want, i have solved it by another way.(constructed MyAdapter with the object View,then i can direct get the view)

Comment: You should probably use a handler to notify your activity