# Listview is not getting updated with notifyDataSetChanged method

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to update my listview with notifyDataSetChanged() this method, but listview is not getting updated, if i press back button and go to previous activity and then again if i come in this activity then it is getting updated, i don't know why. I tried all possible solution but not getting proper solution. Please help Below is my code.

Here is a link which i tried

[ListView not getting updated on calling notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238153/listview-not-getting-updated-on-calling-notifydatasetchanged)

[notifyDataSetChanged() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396450/notifydatasetchanged-not-working)

[notifyDataSetChanged Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378845/notifydatasetchanged-android-listview)

[notifyDataSetChanged not updating ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991411/notifydatasetchanged-not-updating-listview)

[The event of notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278427/the-event-of-notifydatasetchanged)

```
public class Assignment extends Activity {

ListView mListView;
ImageView imageViewCrtAsnm;
String[] stg1;
List<String[]> names2 = null;
DataManipulator dataManipulator;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.assignment);

    imageViewCrtAsnm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.createassignment);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displaydata);

    imageViewCrtAsnm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Assignment.this,
                    Assignment_Create.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                final int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Assignment.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Data");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to Delete Record!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    String[] delete = names2.get(position);
                                    String idString = delete[0];
                                    long idLong = Long.valueOf(idString);
                                    Log.d("Deleting...", idLong + "");
                                    dataManipulator.delete(idLong);
                                    names2.remove(position);

                                    stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
                                    int x = 0;
                                    String stg;

                                    for (String[] name : names2) {
                                        stg = "Title : " + name[1] + "\n"
                                                + "Descr : " + name[2]
                                                + "\n" + "Day's Left : "
                                                + name[3];
                                        stg1[x] = stg;
                                        x++;
                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
    names2 = dataManipulator.selectAll();

    stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
    int x = 0;
    String stg;

    for (String[] name : names2) {
        stg = "Title : " + name[1] + "\n" + "Descr : " + name[2] + "\n"
                + "Day's Left : " + name[3];
        stg1[x] = stg;
        x++;
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stg1);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.check,
            stg1));
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: If you `tried all possible solution` then there is no solution. But seriously you should at least point out what have you tried, so others will not suggest you these solutions.

Comment: @Tafari, i have edited my question with link which i have tried and still there is other link also but i can't update all

Comment: no worries, it's ok now, should keep it that way : ) Just to your knowledge it wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: that is fine. No issues but thanks for suggestion. I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this.

Just use onResume method to call adapter class...

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    names2 = dataManipulator.selectAll();

    stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
    int x = 0;
    String stg;

    for (String[] name : names2) {
        stg = "Title : " + name[1] + "\n" + "Descr : " + name[2] + "\n"
                + "Day's Left : " + name[3];
        stg1[x] = stg;
        x++;
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.assignment_custom,
            stg1);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.assignment_icon);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
    mListView.invalidateViews();
}
```

Just call this part of code in onResume method and you are done. But anyway thanks to all who have helped me. i am posting this answer here so may be other's can take benefit and not waste time like i did.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayAdapter` makes a copy of your items that you pass to it in the constructor and uses that internally.

[ArrayAdapter Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)

So simply manipulating your original array means nothing to the adapter. You are notifying it that the data has changed when it has not changed at all, it still holds the original list you populated it with.

You need to either recreate the entire adpater again or use the `clear`, `addAll`, `remove` or `insert` methods to manipulate the data.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Exactly, Adapter copies and recreates array so just changing original reference wont bring any change.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating your array when you remove data. Have you tried also recreating your adapter to use the new array?

Comment: If i remove my remove method then also it is not updating.

Comment: That is not what I said.